# converting a java application to restful uri

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, restful-url

I am writing a java code which gets the JSON formatted data from a Webservice (with POST call). And I convert this to a text formatted file and move to destination folder.

- In order for other service to POST data(the JSON file which is input for file conversion in my code) how to do I create it as a service?
- How do I create the RESTFul URI for this piece of code?

It would be great if any one helps on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: The title of your question is misleading based on what your actual question says. Please consider re-writing your question: you want to write a code that retrieves a JSON data from a Web Service and then storing this JSON in a text file - but the rest of your question is really confusing and makes it difficult for the community to help. Also remember to indicate what you have tried so far and what errors you have encountered.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005101/how-to-send-json-data-to-post-restful-service

Answer (score 0):

Use spring and create rest controller. With this, it's very easy to create a REST API than any conventional approach. [Click here](https://www.genuitec.com/spring-frameworkrestcontroller-vs-controller/)